# Contruct json into Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to construct the following json into a Map<String, Object>

```
{"tm":"3-ticker-payout-history-full-screen","r":"ES","default_tab":"overview","slug":"alt-group","only":["meta","data","thead"]}
```

Below is what I have so far

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("tm", "3-ticker-payout-history-full-screen");
map.put("slug", "alt-group");
map.put("r", "ES");
map.put("default_tab", "overview");
```

How would I add `"only":["meta","data","thead"]` to the hashmap?

Comment: `map.put("only", Arrays.asList("meta","data","thead"));`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `List<String>` and add `"meta","data","thead"` to the list, then add the `List<String>` to the map.